# Are there some kind of "Reverse Wildcards" in SAP OpenSQL?

Tags: abap, opensql

So we have a table with a field that contains strings.
These strings can contain wildcards.

For example:

```
id | name
---+----------------
 1 | thomas
 2 | san*
 3 | *max*
```

Now I want to select from that table with respect to these wildcards.
For example something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'sandra'.
```

That SELECT should fetch the record with ID = 2 from my table.
Note that it would be ok to use `%` instead of `*` as the wildcard character in the table.

Any way to achieve this in OpenSQL?

Comment: What is the size (in rows) of the table?

Comment: @vwegert: Not sure yet, but not too many. Presumably under 1.000 records.

Comment: In that case I'd probably go for a pragmatic approach and do the filtering in ABAP. I'm quite sure that what you're looking for is not provided in OpenSQL

Comment: While it's impossible in OpenSQL, if you have HANA-based installation, you can achieve it by using [RegExp](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/b4/0d483dd34d47aa9cc89b4d8a6e617e/content.htm).

Answer (score -2):

You can use wildcards, just the sign (like Matecki said), is %.

Take a look here:

https://scn.sap.com/thread/1418148

Additionally  You could create and use a ranges table in the where clause. If You do not know, what it is, and how it can be done, just tell me. Populate the ranges table like this: OPTION = CP, SIGN = I, LOW = san.

Ok for You?

**UPDATE:**

I was wrong and changed the answer

Comment: I know what an ABAP range table is, but I don't see how this would help in my case. Could you elaborate on your answer a bit please -- how would the SELECT statement look like?

Comment: I don't think this right. Does not OpenSQL have a "like" comparison operator that accepts at least wildcards "%" and "_" ?